# How to display multiple records in java?

Tags: mysql, jsp, pagination, split

I have connected to one MySql table to fetch 1000 records that need to be displayed using JSP. I want to split my table into multiple tables (of size 50) which can be viewed by using next button on jsp page. How can I implement it?

```
String sql = "select * from people";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
while(result.next()) {                               // here i get 1000 records. how can i display these records on mulitple jsp pages?
// ... get column values from this record
}
```

Above gives 1000 records and I use a PreparedStatement.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. This sounds a little like you're asking for someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can fetch the complete table in JSP.

Just add one more param to the function returning the ROWS `COUNTER`

Add COUNTER to `LIMIT` clause in your QUERY.

Now you need to keep track of the `COUNTER` so Update the URL on click on next as

> First Click -  URL?pageCOUNTER=1
>     Second Click -  URL?pageCOUNTER=2

Fetch the `pageCOUNTER` varaible from URL and pass it to your function as COUNTER

And so on. Keep getting you result.

OR USE JAVASCRIPT TABLE - http://www.datatables.net/